# What is the first game to have first-person cutscenes where you can’t move the character but you can turn their head?

Tags: gaming-history

In many Bethesda-publisher games, such as *Dishonored* and *Skyrim*, you can move your head during cutscenes. Sometimes, the camera pulls you in a certain direction, like with the cutscenes with the Outsider in *Dishonored 2*, and sometimes you can almost fully move your head while stuff happen, e.g. while a boat your in moves. Other than in some of the Bethesda games I’ve played, you can do this in *BioShock*. **What is the first game to have cutscenes in first-person where you can rotate the camera but otherwise can’t move?**

Comment: On-topic as per [a highly upvoted answer on Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13432/218092)

Answer (score 1):

I remember that Half Life was hailed as the very first game where it does not cut the camera away from the First Person Perspective to do a cutscene (and pretty much no breaking the first person camera for the whole game). So I would guess that is the answer to your question.

Half Life.

Can't find an article that says exactly what I'm saying but here is the closest I've got from a [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/games/2018/nov/21/half-life-at-20-valve-shooter-sci-fi-horror)

> The brilliance of Half-Life begins with its immersive storytelling. The opening accustoms us to the Black Mesa research facility, tells us a little about Freeman’s role and sets up the narrative universe – all without leaving his perspective.